# Sending commands to Roomba from PC

Tags: irobot-create, roomba

I'm trying to send some commands to the Roomba. However is behaving strange.

This is the manual that I'm using.
http://www.irobot.com/~/media/MainSite/PDFs/About/STEM/Create/create_2_Open_Interface_Spec.pdf

First of all. I have consulted several manuals, some of them say that the default baudrate is 115200, however it works for me at 57200.

I'm trying to get a response from the Roomba sending the following comand

Examples:
• To turn on iRobot Create’s Play LED only:
128 132 139 2 0 0

However, the Roomba goes crazy and start going around. Any idea what's happening or what I'm not doing? Or what should I do first?

Thank you.

Comment: what version of Roomba do you have?

Answer (score 1):

iRobot Create and Rommba does not support the same functionality. A SCI manual for the Roomba could be found here: [Roomba SCI spec](http://www.robotappstore.com/files/KB/Roomba/Roomba_SCI_Spec_Manual.pdf).

It works for me by sending plain byte sequence's.

Could you add some more information to your question:

- How do you connect to the Roomba physical?
- How are you sending data to the Roomba logical?

Meta Remark: I would like to use the comment function but do not have enough reputation.

Comment: Yes, the Roomba does not support the same API as the command module in the old Create.  However, the Create has been re-released (as Create 2) with no command module.  Now the only interface is SCI (Serial Command Interface) aka OI (Open Interface).  This hasn't changed much from version to version, and I believe even the old Create supported it.  The link you posted is for older Roombas, the link anfedres posed is for Roombas version 500 and above.

Answer (score 1):

If your robot communicates at 57600 baud, then it is a Roomba 400 series robot, and you should use the manual that En3rGy posted, not the one for Create 2. That said, the LEDs command (139) is identical in all versions of Create and Roomba, so clearly something else is going on. Try a baud rate of 57600. It's possible that when you send data at 57200, some data corruption is happening as Create tries to interpret it at 57600 baud.